# Caml LookupId and LookupValue

Tags: 2013, caml-query, caml, xml, query

I need to get the **LookupId value** and the **lookup text value** by **CAML**.
With this query I get the ID but I can not get the value text anymore.

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>ListName</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="MyLookUP" LookupId="true"/>
    <FieldRef Name="MyLookUP" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

In MyLookUP I have always the ID of the lookup, I wish the value and the ID

Comment: Can you post entire CAML query? Why do you have MyLookUP field referenced twice? Did you try to omit last FieldRef element and have only one MyLookUP FieldRef element

Comment: Is just simple query for a report, I have to group dy Id and display the label of the group (text of the lookup)

Comment: Did you try to omit last `FieldRef` element and have only one MyLookUP `FieldRef` element?

Comment: yes and I get the id number